# I am looking for a possible options to find out the relavent tables that are getting altered when a transaction happend in the UI

Tags: database

I have one requirement to check:
When I create an entry using web GUI, what are all tables or DBs are getting added with this new change?

- or when we run a curl commands by pointing to Sever, what are all tables or DBs are getting added with this new change?

Please provide me your suggestions...

Comment: the question is too abstract and unclear

Comment: Hi @AlexShesterov, For an example, i have created a new entry in GUI. So, the entry information will be saved in database and in one / more of tables. So, i would like to know, what are all those tables will be affecting by this new entry. Hope this is clear now.